# Joomla 3 articles category template override not working

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding

I try to override an article category template with file newslist.php located in \templates\mediavolga\html\com_content\category\newslist.php

I set this file as alternative layout in category settings, but it does't works.

What I'am doing wrong, how to override default category blog template?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default category blog template, then it needs to have the same name as the default does. Try this:
1) copy all the files in components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/ into the folder  \templates\mediavolga\html\com_content\category\
2) edit them and add an "echo 'this is my override blog.php'" to the files. If you see the output, then you can start modifying it.